# Cast or mirror PC or laptop screen to TV connected over wired LAN

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, tv, mirroring, dlna

How can I stream cast my laptop (running Windows 8.1) screen to a Samsung TV?

Provided:

1. TV is connected to LAN over wire (it is not wireless)
2. Laptop is also over the same LAN but wireless
3. Found TV under devices and printers (Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Devices and Printers)

Things that I've tried:

1. Tried projecting to second screen but couldn't find the TV under the listed devices - FAILED
2. Under devices I am able to find 3 options Play, Print and Project.

   1. TV does not get listed under Project. -  FAILED
   2. Play shows message "You can only play from apps" - FAILED
3. I do not want to connect through HDMI or VGA cables, because then it will limit my mobility with my laptop. - WON'T WORK

Answer (score 1):

Something we do all the time here at home - we use Chromecast - and the way I've set it up we can connect either over wifi, or if needs be with ethernet.

It does mean buying a chromecast, but well worth it and great for streaming movies etc or youtube from an app. They are great value for money in my opinion.

This should get you started.
http://www.howtogeek.com/199565/mirror-anything-from-your-computer-to-your-tv-using-google-chromecast/

Then we use a small wireless controller that fits in one hand to move the mouse or type - really frees you up from the actual PC or Laptop.

APe

Comment: I should add that if you want to Chromecast over LAN, you need an adapter. Google sell them but if you search ebay, you can find very cheap alternatives and the OTG cable to make it all work very easily - Plug and Play!
I've got 4 of these using the LAN to chromecast here.  I did that over WIFI because at the time our WIFI signal was terrible and the Ethenet adapters were awesome, never missed a beat. Had them connected up with Powerline AV500 network plugs but can just as easily run a cable.